# Remove old site indexes from google search

Tags: content-management-system, seo, google-custom-search

I have one CMS which was revamped & all the urls are changed. 
But in google search it is showing all old urls which are not active now. 
How can i remove these indexed pages from the google search. 
Is there any way to do this from webmaster tool?

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663416

Comment: Yes for removing the old links, I need to provide the 404 headers for the old pages or if the pages are moved to another url we need to provide 301 header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also put a redirect on the page(s) and/or directories, with a R=301 which means a permanent redirect. Googlebot will adhere to that.

Also @JC's link above shows that eventually the old pages will fall off page rank (only took a couple of days with a site that gets ~250,000 hits a day).

I've successfully seen/done both of these.